# Difference between Raman scattering and compton effect

Tags: photons, scattering

While studying modern physics, I came across the Compton effect, which states that when photons are scattered by free electrons, their (photons') wavelength changes.

This sentence suffices the condition of inelastic scattering. But while calculating the change in wavelength of scattered photons, Compton used conditions of elastic collision. So, I wanted to ask two things here,

1. Is the Compton effect similar to Raman scattering, and if not, what is the difference between them?
2. Secondly, is it an elastic collision between photon and electron that leads to inelastic scattering?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m not getting the connection to Raman scattering at all, other than the photon wavelength changes…